# Luigi workflow engine command line parameters not being passed to workers in macOS

Tags: python, arguments, workflow, luigi

I am experiencing some problems when trying to pass global parameters to multiple workers. When I run a workflow using multiple workers, the command line parameter values are not being passed. I am wondering if this might be similar to the problem observed when luigi is run on Windows ([#2247](https://github.com/spotify/luigi/issues/2247)) but, in my case, on macOS. An additional issue is a difference in log formatting, it seems that `logging.cfg` is not passed to the workers. I opened a ticket in github but I got no response ([#3236](https://github.com/spotify/luigi/issues/3236)).

Next toy example summarizes my problem.

```py
import luigi
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('luigi-interface')

class HelloConfig(luigi.Config):
    reference = luigi.Parameter(default="World")

class HelloTask(luigi.Task):
    def run(self):
        logger.info("Hello %s!", HelloConfig().reference)

    def requires(self):
        return []
```

I run the task calling

```bash
luigi --module weekly_update.etl.load_ex HelloTask \
      --workers ? \
      --HelloConfig-reference "Mars"
```

When `workers` is 1 the log shows

```
2023-04-21 10:59:09,386 - luigi-interface - INFO - [MainThread] - Hello Mars!
```

but when `workers` is 2

```
2023-04-21 10:59:53,030 [INFO]-load_ex.run: Hello World!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of [Python 3.8, MacOS now defaults to using spawn instead of fork](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#multiprocessing), thus having issues that we previously only saw on Windows. You can change the start method using

```
import multiprocessing

multiprocessing.set_start_method('fork')
```

I'm not sure there is a better solution, and we're also struggling with command line parameters across multiple workers when not on Linux.